# C++ STL set implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

Why is the C++ set implemented as a binary tree instead of as a hashset, which can provide average case complexity of O(1) as compared to the O(log n) provided by a binary tree?

Comment: This question might be better phrased as why didn't the STL have a hashset/unordered_set in addition to the ordered set from the start?  Of course, then the question would probably be closed as not being answerable or being argumentative. All I know is that Stepanov's original STL proposal didn't have `hash_set` (I'm not sure when SGI added it to their STL but I think it was before the 1998 standard was final).

Comment: @MichaelBurr your comment is closer to an answer to the actual question than any of the answers given so far.

Comment: Because a hash table can also provide worst case lookup complexity of O(n) as compared to O(log n) provided by a binary tree.

Comment: Looks just bad naming to me. `set` should be `ordered_set`, and `unordered_set` just `set`. Ordering isn't intrinsic to set-ness. The same goes for `map`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because C++ sets are ordered by the `T`'s comparison operator, which makes it possible to iterate over the members in a predictable way.  If you know that all you will do with the set is insert, test membership, and/or remove elements, then `std::unordered_set`, which implements a hashset, exists for that since C++11.

Comment: Almost word for word with what I had :p

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't get it. Aren't C++ sets ordered by T's comparison operator because they are implemented as a binary tree? Or is it the other way around? Seems like circular logic.

Comment: @user2380088 The binary tree embodies the ordering; the existence of a comparison operator is what makes the ordering possible.

Comment: Right, but why the choice of binary tree over a hashset?

Comment: @user2380088 With a binary tree, if you increment an iterator you know that it will point to the next 'largest' element in the set, as dictated by `<`.  With a hashset you don't know anything like this, since it's generally opaque what `<` is for a hash function.

Comment: @user2380088, because while a hashset has very good lookup complexity, it's not necessarily good for in-order processing since the order of the hashes may bear little relation to the order of the keys.

Comment: This doesn't answer *why* though.

Answer (score 10):

According to John Nagle, from a 2006 posting to [comp.lang.c++.moderated](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c++.moderated/l1-otd0zffg/mHCcTE3kEuoJ):

> The actual reason is that the person who was writing the
>   hash table part of the spec didn't finish it in time.
>   That's all.

Standardization processes are like that.

Comment: That's why hash sets/maps weren't also included, but the intent was always that both binary-tree and hash based associative containers would be available (my reading of the question is that it presupposes a choice between the two).

Comment: This is the only real answer. Both kind of containers are useful and desirable in a stdlibrary. One simply didn't make it in time for shipping.

Comment: That's quite an oversimplification.

Answer (score 1):

There are two factors here:

- both binary tree and hash based associative sets are useful
- the original STL only implemented the former due to a lack of time to work through the "politics" of Standarisation; SGI, GNU, MS, boost and others have provided non-Standard hash-based versions for many years, and C++11 introduces `unordered_set`

These points are discussed below.

### BOTH ARE USEFUL

There are lots of pros/cons, and both are available (as of C++11) to let the programmer choose.  Hash-based sets were not available because there simply wasn't agreement on the implementation in time for them to be included in earlier standards.

- `set` iteration is in sort order, whereas a hashed container `unsorted_set` is effectively randomised-order traversal

  - `set` supports `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, which aren't practical to provide on an `unsorted_set`
- `set` uses a comparison function (by default the contained type's `operator<`, whereas `unordered_set` requires a hashing function (defaults are provided for some types but they can be pretty mediocre depending on your actual keys, and quality hashing can be time consuming) and a key equality function
- either may be faster for smaller values of N - not everyone's dealing with billions of elements so it's sensible to offer choice even from a performance perspective
- there may be significant differences in memory usage for small objects, though I'm not sure what overall guidelines would be true across implementations so can just suggest measuring in your program if you care
- as elements are added, existing iterators into a `std::unordered_set` may be invalidated (see 23.2.5p14 for when exactly), whereas iterators into a `std::map` are never invalidated by inserts (pointers and references to `unordered_set` elements remain valid though).

### Why earlier C++ Standards didn't have a hash based set

From an interview with Stepanov:

> Question: I find two hash table implementations in the D.Musser site, and they were both working and quite smart - much smarter than hash tables commonly found in class libraries. Why were hash tables not included into STL?
>
> Answer: Politics. They have to be in. Our new implementation of STL does contain them. In general, we need to develop a mechanism for adding things to STL. After all, STL is an extensible framework, it begs to be extended. There are many data structures that are missing, for example, singly linked lists, matrices, and graphs. SGI is willing to lead the way in extending STL.

(full interview at http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html)

Comment: unordered_sets are implemented with bucket chains, not with open addressing (23.2.5p9). Consequently, elements do not move, although their iteration order may change, so a reference to an element is valid until the element is removed (23.2.5p14). Sparseness is not much of an issue; at any event, it does not require maintaining space for unused nodes, only for bucket heads (which are just pointers). Your first two points are fine, though.

Comment: @rici: ahhh... didn't realise the values weren't stored by value... "The number of buckets is automatically increased as elements are added to an unordered associative container, so that the average number of elements per bucket is kept below a bound. Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and changes which buckets elements appear in, but does not invalidate pointers or references to elements.".  Will correct accordingly - thanks.